# Create a .lnk file to shell location?

Tags: windows, shortcuts

How would I create a `.lnk` file to this path?

```
shell:::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}\::{1FA9085F-25A2-489B-85D4-86326EEDCD87}
```

This should open the 'Manage Wireless Networks' window where you can view your saved networks.

It works fine from the 'Run' dialog, but when entered into a `.lnk` file, it says

> The name 'shell:::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}::{1FA9085F-25A2-489B-85D4-86326EEDCD87}' specified in the Target box is not valid. Make sure the path and file name are correct.

I know this is possible as I've done it before, however I can't seem to find the webpage which said how (I think it was on http://sevenforums.com somewhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.lnk` file should point to:

```
explorer.exe shell:::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}\::{1FA9085F-25A2-489B-85D4-86326EEDCD87}
```

I just found this after I asked from here: http://teamwindows8.com/2013/05/ultimate-list-of-shell-locations-in-windows-8/

Answer (score 1):

Open the Dialog in Windows Explorer and move the icon to the desktop by holding the left mouse button.

[image]

This generates a proper shortcut which works fine.

Comment: Yes, I think this was how I originally did managed to do this (a while ago).

Comment: and why are you no longer using it? This is much faster as your way and you don't need to know this strings numbers.